# Curved UITableView/UIScrollView

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview

I am trying to build an app that gives users a scroll option on the side (a UITableView or a UIScrollView) that is curved/elliptic, but I don't really know where to start so I would appreciate some help.

The idea would be to have the scroll/table look like this:

```
A
 B
  C      Rest of screen
 D
E
```

I look forward to hearing some ideas.

Comment: What about positioning the row content? I mean changing the x offset of cell's content based on row index.

Comment: Isn't that quite a bit of processing if you have many cells? Scrolling through the subviews of each cell to move them around isn't ideal. And as far as I know there isn't a setContentOffset for UITableViewCell, right?

Comment: You are adding subview to ur cell and you can set frame for your subview,rt? So i guess that wnt be a prblm.. regarding processing, i'm not sure... I feel like it can be done by checking row index(jst by considering the example u posted on questn)

Answer (score 0):

I once did a nice looking scroll view where you could scroll through thumbnails horizontally. I created a "curved" effect by making the images towards the center larger, similar to cover flow. It is quite simple, just change the `transform` based on the position in `viewDidScroll`. I think that would perhaps be a similar effect to what you are looking for.